# What is Complete and General Integral of a PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

We often hear some basic notions such as complete integral and general integral of a PDE and also envelope while studying PDEs.

Could you explain what are the differences between them?

I can' t visualize in my brain the notions. How to imagine the notions?

Thanks.

Comment: Look up [(Lagrange-)Charpit equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=charpit+complete+), and characteristic curves. There are numerous examples here, some even with complete solutions and discussions of shock curves (in the case of the Burgers equation).

Comment: Ok, could you explain the differences between them? I can' t find it.

Comment: See the comment by user8268 in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35145/complete-vs-general-integral-of-first-order-pde.